# apple-music tag != music.app tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked this question recently:

[Music collection is not sorted by Album on iOS 8.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194038/music-collection-is-not-sorted-by-album-on-ios-8-4)

And I noticed that an edit was approved to remove [music.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music.app) tag and add [apple-music](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-music) tag.

My question has nothing to do with Apple Music.  Apple Music is a streaming service, where the Music App is what comes pre-installed on Apple Devices.  I was having a playlist issue and that is specific to the Music App.

I don't have enough rep to reject the edit, but I also don't want to just edit again and change the tag, which will prompt the original editors to just retag, etc. etc…

Is Apple Music the new Music App?

Comment: The Music app CAN be used to access Apple Music, but in this case you are not accessing Apple Music, just local music, so you don't need the Apple Music tag.

Answer (score 7):

That edit should have been rejected. [apple-music](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-music) is not an appropriate tag here as this is nothing to do with Apple Music, the music streaming service. Unfortunately, no-one reads the tag wiki excerpts, let alone tag wikis, and [I've been there](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/new-users-dont-tag-questions-correctly). [music.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music.app) tag is the appropriate tag here and I've edited the question to use that tag.

By the way, you don't need more reputation to review suggested edits to your own posts. Opening the suggested edit from the inbox notification will allow you to approve/reject the suggested edit should it have not already been approved/rejected.

I've left a note in the revision history pointing to this meta post and commented to ping the editor.